# How to select design pattern for a project or struct code for a project and assign task code for members in project

Tags: planning, software-development

I am newbie in PM and I wonder

- how to create frame code for project  tasks of project manager.
- task of member
- task of design graphic (web)

Please suggest me any toturial or book.

Answer (score 1):

The majority of number systems for tasks I have seen are related to the Work Breakdown Structure and and follow the [Top].[Next Level].[Next Level] pattern using simple integer numbers (i.e. 3.5.6, 2.1.15.3) that is standard for a lot of government documents (and the PMBoK itself).